# Issue with falling object when moving from side to side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object

I have two sets of falling cubes, one set falls normally and the other should move from side to side while falling (let’s call this the moving cube and the other the normal cube to keep this a little less confusing). Both cubes fall at the same speed as I’m using a variable to control how fast both blocks fall and both have the same variable amount.

I’ve got an issue with the moving cubes, as when they move from side-to-side, they also start gradually moving upwards, as if they’re slowing down rather then falling at a consistent speed like to other normal cubes. When I turn off the side-to-side movement, it falls down fine alongside the normal cubes.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Cube_Moving : MonoBehaviour
{
     public static float verticalSpeed = 350;
     private Rigidbody2D cube_RB;
   
     private int moveHorizontal = 0;
     private int horizontalSpeed = 5;

     void Start()
     {
         cube_RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
       
         moveHorizontal = Random.Range(1, 3);
     }

     void Update()
     {
         if (transform.position.y <= -6)
         {
             Destroy(gameObject);
         }
         if (transform.position.x < -1.65f)
         {
             moveHorizontal = 1;
         }
         else if (transform.position.x > 1.65f)
         {
             moveHorizontal = 2;
         }
     }

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         cube_RB.velocity = transform.up * -verticalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
         if (moveHorizontal == 1)
         {
             transform.position += transform.right * (horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
         else if (moveHorizontal == 2)
         {
             transform.position -= transform.right * (horizontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         }
     }
}
```

I have a separate script for the normal cubes (they’re separate prefabs) which is the same apart from the code that includes `moveHorizontal`, which triggers the side-to-side movement.

As I thought it might be that the moving cube is slowing down, I tried increasing the moving cubes falling speed to try and counteract this but it doesn’t seem to work. Increasing the speed results the moving cube falling quicker in a zig zag movement rather than moving upwards.

Here is the script for the normal cube:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float verticalSpeed = 350;

    private Rigidbody2D cube_RB;
    
    void Start()
    {
        cube_RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.y <= -6)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        cube_RB.velocity = transform.up * -verticalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

I've also provided an image of my Rigidbody settings just for reference:

[image: I've also provided an image of my Rigidbody settings just for reference.]

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue you are facing. Can you post the other script for the normal cubes? [This is what i get](https://imgur.com/a/bFKgaUZ) when i disable the side to side motion in the script you provided. It seems to work just fine

Comment: @DekuDesu Thanks for the reply and for looking in to this. So there must be something i'm doing thats causing this issue if you got it working, but i'm not sure what. I've added the script for the normal cube as requested. 

I've also provided an image of my rigidbody settings for the normal cube. The only difference with this and the moving cube is that the moving cube is Kinematic. I've changed it to dynamic, set interpolate to none and still get same issue.

I should also point out that i am Instantiating the cubes, not sure if that makes a difference but worth noting just in case.

Comment: No problem! I went ahead and copy pasted both scripts, [both work completely as intended](https://i.imgur.com/ucfooCD.mp4). Make sure that you're not accidentally effecting these objects with other scripts.

Comment: Cheers for that. At least my code is working as intended. I'll take a look and see if i can work out whats happening on my end.

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to find out the what issue was. It was the Interpolate settings which was causing the issue. I was using Interpolate to smooth the falling motion as without it, the falling motion was quite jittery. I had Interpolate on for both the moving and normal cubes and had only tested switching one of them to none.

Once i switched both cubes Interpolate to none, it worked as intended. I ended up changing the falling movement from RB velocity to transform.position to sort out the jittery motion.

Thanks again for the help.